# How to convert array-like string to an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

I want to use array syntax inside a string value and then add that variable in `array()`.

Like:

```
$value= "'user_type'=>'test','username'=>'test'";
$form_data = array($value);
```

The desired assignment should be:

```
$form_data = array('user_type'=>'test','username'=>'test');
```

but this is not what I get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to associative array PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569829/convert-string-to-associative-array-php)

Comment: The above dupe link is justified, but I will say this is an ever-so-slightly different snowflake because it doesn't have the optional spaces around the delimiting commas.  While I support the dupe vote/flags, I have elected to post an answer that is uniquely designed for the more predictable format of this question's sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `JSON` transformation. This should work:

```
// create a JSON string like:
$value = '{ "user_type":"test", "username":"test" }';
$form_data = json_decode($value, true);
// test it
var_dump($form_data);
```

Comment: Please include the (programmatic) "preparation magic" that is omitted from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method using `parse_str()` -- which is an intuitive, loop-free one-liner.  It seems like the best choice to me -- I mean this is the very purpose of the function!  Like any robust solution for this task, it does need careful preparation.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1215d7c973a081f85d1e690ec73293eb13540ad4))

```
$value= "'user_type'=>'test1','username'=>'test2','monkey\'s wrench'=>'that\'s trouble'";
parse_str(stripslashes(str_replace(["'=>'","','"],['=','&'],trim($value,"'"))),$form_data);  // second param is output variable
var_export($form_data);
```

This will serve you well, unless your "keys" or "values" contain the delimiting substrings.

- First the leading and trailing single quotes are trimmed off
- Then `str_replace()` will modify the delimiters:

  - `'=>'` becomes `=`
  - `','` becomes `&`
- Then `stripslashes()` handles any escaping slashes.
- Finally, `parse_str()` works its magic to directly produce the associative array.

> My method will not work out-of-the-box on the duplicate link on the question because of the `(string)` prefix and the optional spacing around the delimiting commas.  My method is specifically suited to this strictly-structured, one-dimensional, associative, array-like string.

A method using `preg_match()` with a carefully designed pattern may be trustworthy, but regex is categorically slower than string functions and may appear a little convoluted to the untrained eye.

A method using `eval()` is possible as well, but that function should only be used as a "Plan Z" when all else fails to do the job well AND the values need to be heavily validated/filtered with extreme prejudice.

A method using `explode()` and a `foreach()` loop will require a larger code block and I assume it will be a slower alternative (but maybe not).  Exploding on any single character will run a higher risk of mangling data; like with all solutions extra attention to preserving data intregity is essential.

verjas' method seems a logical approach, but when replacing single quotes with double quotes, keys and values that contain quotes may get mangled.  I will leave the preparation code to verjas to accommodate single and double quotes.